# mount error(115): Operation now in progress

Tags: rhel, mount, cifs, shared-folders, nas

I'm having an issue **mounting a shared NAS drive that is hosted on a Windows 2000 server**. This is a drive that I'm certain I have access to, and I frequently access it from a Windows 7 machine and a Windows Server 2008 machine. Now, **I'm attempting to mount this drive from a RHEL7 machine**, but I'm having some issues.

**What I've done:**

```
mkdir /mnt/neededFolder
mount -t cifs //DNS.forMyDrive.stuff/neededFolder /mnt/neededFolder -o username=myUserId,password=myPassword,domain=myDomain
```

**What I expected:**
I expected to be able to access the folder at */mnt/neededFolder*

**What actually happened:**
The error I'm receiving (partially shown in the subject line here) is

```
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

**What the log says:**

**dmesg** output:

```
[1712257.661259] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[1712257.662098] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

We can all see that there is a connection issue, that is obvious. I know both machines are connected to the network. **What can I try next to get this drive mounted?**

**EDIT:** It may be worth noting that I am able to ping the DNS name and the raw IP of the remote location that I am trying to mount.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/430163/cifs-share-mount-errors have you tried everything in this? If not go for that first.

Comment: @DeclanGallagher I'll check it out right now, thanks Declan. I'll report back if anything in there works for me!

Comment: Try mounting via the IP address as opposed to the DNS name

Comment: @RamanSailopal I have tried this and the error is the same :(

Comment: Very similar question and the answer is there in the question itself. Check it out,  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mount-error-115-on-some-shares-4175499264/

Comment: @Buddika that person's problem was with the IP address being wrong. I'm not in that boat. I've tried with the DNS and the IP typed in. It may be worth noting, I can ping the DNS from the RHEL7 machine I'm attempting to mount at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue ended up being that the route to the NAS was missing. Once the route was added, I was able to mount the drive with ease.

```
route add-net x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: So you're saying this was a network error? Initially you wrote that you could ping both the IP and the DNS name, how did that work if the routing was wrong?

Comment: @ketil I had to delete my previous response here, to you, after noticing that my Jul 18th 2018 comment clarified that I was indeed able to ping the desired location from the RHEL7 machine I was working with.

Comment: Mine was a firewall blocking

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when mounting a remote windows 10 SAMBA drive on ubuntu 18.04. After waiting for 10 minutes and running the same command, it worked normally. Maybe the problem can sometimes be caused by something slow on the server side?

Comment: I'm running into this, where the mount fail with "mount error(115): Operation now in progress" and then it works the next try

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem after I got windows 10 update 1809. 
The windows firewall was blocking the access. 
There is a predefined rule for inbound SMB conections that was not activated for private network.

Funny thing: It seems to be activated for public networks....

Comment: I also had to enable the netlogon service rule in my firewall before I could successfully mount.

Comment: This behavior may have been caused by the fact that the query whether the "PC can be found by other devices in this network" has not been answered with "yes". The matching firewall rule has to be activated manually then.

Comment: The built-in firewall rule only allows connections on the "Local subnet", so you may have to create an additional firewall rule for TCP port 445, especially if using VPN. Also if using VPN, make sure you set the network profile (e.g. with [Set-NetConnectionProfile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/set-netconnectionprofile?view=win10-ps)) on the VPN connection, rather than your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mount-error-115-on-some-shares-4175499264/): make sure your box is able to resolve the sharing server hostname properly. In my case I had to correct record in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the network path with the IP address of sharing device

[image: 1]

Comment: This worked for me. Somehow //NAS/ wasn't resolving over openVPN